# Understanding Why a Product of Cyclic Groups with Non-Coprime Orders is not Cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, products

Let $G_1, G_2, \ldots, G_t$ be finite cyclic groups, and define $G = G_1 \times G_2 \times \ldots \times G_t$. Let $n_j = |G_j|$, such that $|G| = \prod_{j=1}^{t} n_j$.

For part (a) of the problem, we are asked to suppose that $\gcd(n_i, n_j) > 1$ for some $i \neq j$ and show that $G$ is not cyclic.

I understand that a group $G$ is cyclic if there exists an element $g \in G$ such that every element of $G$ can be written as $g^k$ for some integer $k$. My attempt to solve this part is based on the hint given:

Hint: Show that the order of any element is less than $n$, where $n = \prod_{j=1}^{t} n_j$.

Here is my incomplete attempt:

I started by considering an arbitrary element $(g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_t) \in G$, where each $g_j$ is a generator of $G_j$. Then, the order of this element would be the least common multiple of the orders of $g_j$, which is $\operatorname{lcm}(|g_1|, |g_2|, \ldots, |g_t|)$.

Since $G_j$ are all cyclic, $|g_j| = n_j$. However, I'm stuck on how to proceed from here. I understand that the $\gcd(n_i, n_j) > 1$ condition should imply that the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of the $n_j$'s is less than the product of the $n_j$'s, but I'm not sure how to show this formally. Can someone help me complete this proof?

Comment: You can use prime factorizations. If a prime $p$ appears in the prime factorizations of the $n_i$ with the powers $r_i$, then it appears in the prime factorization of the lcm with power $\max r_i$, and in the gcd with power $\min r_i$. (Here $r_i=0$ means the prime isn't in the factorization at all).

Comment: Prove it first for just two groups, then prove it for any finite umber of groups by induction. Alternatively, you could look up (or better yet, derive) the formula for the lcm of more than 2 integers.

Comment: @NaturalLogZ i was still not able to write up a good proof :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for all $(g_m)_{m=1}^{t} ∈G$
$$ \text{lcm}(|g_m|) ≤ \text{lcm}(|g_{m ≠ i, j}|)×\text{lcm}(|g_i|, |g_j|) = \text{lcm}(|g_{m ≠ i, j}|)\frac{n_{i}n_{j}}{\text{gcd}(n_i, n_j)} \lt n_jn_i\prod_{m \ne i,j} n_m = |G|$$
as $\text{gcd}(n_i, n_j) > 1$. Thus the order of every element is less than the order of the group.
Alternatively, you could prove that the product $G_i \times G_j$ is non-cyclic, thus the entire product is non-cyclic.